# Interface "Cutting" Across Class Hierarchy

Tags: java, class, interface

I am reading a book that is on android but brushes over some java stuff in a minibook. I already read a book on Java and am aware of interfaces. The books says

> The interface-implementing hierarchy (if you can call it a
>   “hierarchy”) cuts across the class-extension hierarchy. This idea is
>   illustrated in Figure 4-1, where I display class extensions vertically
>   and display interface implementations horizontally. (Android’s
>   KeyboardView class lives in the android.inputmethod service package.
>   Both KeyboardView and the homegrown MyListener class in Listing 4-3
>   implement Android’s OnClickListener interface.)
>
> [image: Interface Cutting Across Classs Heirarchy]
>
> Burd, Barry (2011-11-14). Android Application Development All-in-One
>   For Dummies (p. 197). John Wiley and Sons. Kindle Edition.

Does the "cutting accross class hierchy" just mean that sibling classes both extend the interface... I don't get what more are they pointing out with this diagram and saying it cuts across horizantly the class vertical heirchy in diagram 4-3... Please explain if there is special concepts deeper than what I got out of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `MyListener` and the `KeyboardView`-classes implement the `OnClickListener`-interface. That makes both of those classes `OnClickListener`s.

The idea is the following: Every class derives from a base-class (`Object` being the most basic class available). That makes every class an `Object`. Thinking in terms of OOP, the most abstract thing you can say about *something* is, that it is an object.

Getting back to the interfaces, let's assume you have two interfaces, `Singer` and `Writer`. A person can be a singer, and a person can be a writer. But he/she can also be both.

Implementing `Singer` and/or `Writer` tells you more about an object. Some code:

```
class Guy implements Singer, Writer{
  // Empty
}
Guy chris = new Guy();

hireWriter(chris); // Accepts "Writer" as it's parameter
hireSinger(chris); // Accepts "Singer" as it's parameter
```

By implementing the interfaces, you're telling your code that this object is:

1. An `Object`
2. A `Singer`
3. A `Writer`

This "cut's through the class hierarchy" by providing more information about a class by not deriving from more classes, but by implementing interfaces.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Knuth I think the biggest thing that helped me was not only that it was saying what I thought it was stateing, but how you showed in the hireWriter and hireSigner calls that the Guy class is seen depending on the parameter as two seperate things.